# How to find a specific word using Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, datatables

I`m trying to select DataTable rows using regex. I want to found all rows that have only the word "Venta" and omit "Renta/Venta" and also "Renta".

Examples of possibles strings:

"whatever whatever Venta/Renta whatever"

"whatever whatever Venta whatever "

"whatever whatever Renta whatever "

I only want to select the string that only have "Venta" alone. Now I using "(?!Renta/Venta)Venta" but still selects the rows that have "Renta/Venta".

Comment: does `venta` have spaces on both sides?

Answer (score 0):

Use the whitespace character (`\s`):

```
/(^|\s)Venta(\s|$)/
```

Comment: There is no lookbehind in JavaScript

Comment: Good catch. In that case, just capture the whitespace and since we're only testing, not using, it doesn't matter. Updating the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check it here: https://regex101.com/r/Ja7Vg8/1

```
.*\bVenta\b[^\/].*
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string are built that way, then you can use a regex with negative lookahead like this:

```
.*Venta(?!\/Renta).*
```

**[working demo](https://regex101.com/r/JIYuK8/1)**

Keep in mind that it won't work if the string is:

```
whatever Renta whatever Venta whatever
```

So, if strings like above are present, then you can use a trick like this:

```
^(.(?!Renta))+$
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/JIYuK8/3)**